# Error with nested class inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-studio-2013

```
class A {};
class B : private A {};
class C : private B
{
public:
    class D : private A {}; // Error here
};
```

This code gives the following error (in VS 2013):

> nested.cpp(8) : error C2247: 'A' not accessible because 'B' uses 'private' to inherit from 'A'

It gets fixed if I change the definition of `D` like this:

```
class D : private ::A {};
```

Is this correct behavior, and if so why?

At first I thought it was because `C` inherits privately from `B` which would hide the base classes. But if I eliminate the "middle man" class `B` and just use this:

```
class A {};
class C : private A
{
public:
    class D : private A {};
};
```

The error goes away.

Comment: The compiler is telling you why. *because 'B' uses 'private' to inherit from 'A'*, not because C inherits privately from B.

Comment: @n.m. Well that doesn't tell me much. After all, I'm using a class from the global namespace and not a member of something. Anyway I get it now thanks to the answers.

Comment: Names are searched from inside out. When a name is found, the search stops. Then accessibility is checked. In your case the search path is C>B>A. B>A is blocked because of private inheritance, A is inaccessible. Which is what the compiler tells you. That A also exists in the global scope, and it's the same A, is irrelevant.

Comment: @n.m. Nope, the compiler didn't tell me all of that...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quote from *[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)*:

> A name that is private according to unqualified name lookup, may be
>   accessible through qualified name lookup

With that in mind lets see how the unqualified name lookup would work for the first example:

```
class A {};

class B : private A {};

class C : private B
{
public:
    class D : private A {}; // Error here
};
```

1. `A` is looked up within the scope of `C`. Had it been defined there, there would be no problem.
2. It figures out `A` is privately inherited by it's base (private) class `B` and hence throws a compiler error.
   Clang says:

   ```
   note: constrained by private inheritance here:
   class B : private A {};
   ```

Again, as per the quote it should work, if you use fully qualified name, like you have shown

```
class D : private ::A {};
```

And as for your last example:

```
class A {};

class C : private A
{
public:
    class D : private A {};
};
```

It works because, the name lookup works for all names that are part of the same class. To quote from cppreference again:

> All members of a class (bodies of member functions, initializers of
>   member objects, and the entire nested class definitions) have access
>   to all the names to which a class can access.

Comment: _It probably figures out_? An answer should be an answer, not another underlying question.

Answer (score 12):

It's a matter of scopes during name lookup:

- When you use `::A` it's a fully qualified name, thus you are explicitly referring to the global namespace and picking `A` up from there.
- When you inherit from `A`, `C` (let me say) sees `A` and you can directly refer to the `A` name within `C` with an unqualified name.
- When you inherit from `B`, `C` *sees* `B` and `A` is private in its scope. It's private, but it exists. Because `A` is an unqualified name and is looked for first of all in that scope, it happens to be found and unaccessible, thus the error.

Answer (score 7):

Example from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access):

```
class A { };
class B : private A { };
class C : public B {
   A* p; // error: unqualified name lookup finds A as the private base of B
   ::A* q; // OK, qualified name lookup finds the namespace-level declaration
};
```

With private inheritance, public and protected member of the base class become private members of the derived class.

```
class B : private A {};

class C : private B
{
public:
    class D : private A {}; // Error because all members of A is private to B so what 
    //would be the use of this private inheritance if you can't access any of A's member.
};
```

While

```
class D :private ::A {};
```

works because A's members are directly taken from global namespace, enabling `D` to have access to `A`'s public and protected members.

Answer (score 4):

A crucial part for understanding, which is not explicitly spelled out in the other answers, is the following:

> The name of a class is injected into the classes' scope.

That is, if you have

```
class A {};
```

then you can refer to class `A` not only by the name `::A` but also by the name `A::A`. Note that despite describing the same class, those are *not* the same name, as they are in different scopes.

Now when in the scope of `A` or a class deriving directly or indirectly from `A`, unqualified lookup will find `A::A` rather than `::A` (unless `A::A` is itself hidden by yet another name).

In addition, unlike some other languages, C++ does not *hide* private names from scopes where you cannot access them, but uses access specifiers only as *permission to use* the name. Moreover, those permissions are bound to the name, not to the named entity (in this case, the class).

So in your code, on unqualified lookup of `A` the compiler finds the name `C::B::A::A` which hides the name `::A`, and then checks the access permission and finds this name is private in the current context, as it is a name in the scope of `C::B::A` which cannot be accessed from within `C` since `A` is a private base class of `B`.

Answer (score 2):

class D : private ::A {};
When you inherit from B, C sees B and A is private in its scope. It's private, but it exists. Because A is an unqualified name and is looked for first of all in that scope, it happens to be found and unaccessible, thus the error.